# Is there a way to have changes automatically colorized in TexMaker?

Tags: texmaker

I am working on a long document. Those reviewing it only want to read the changes, not the entire (multi-hundred page) document over again whenever I make edits. It would be much easier if I didn't have to manually place and remove `{color{red} ... }` blocks to mark the edits, not to mention much easier to remove the colors later. I would obviously need to be able to set a start point and have all changes from then tracked, not just on a save-by-save basis, as each revision would need to be compiled repeatedly during the process. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: have you considered using a version control system, such as `git`? Such software allows for easy viewing of they types of changes you describe, and more :)

Comment: Can't upvote the suggestion of version control enough. Examples: [what did I change on November 14?](http://trac.cae.tntech.edu/ttuthesis/changeset?reponame=&new=87%40trunk%2Fttuthesis.cls&old=86%40trunk%2Fttuthesis.cls) and [what sets of changes have I ever done?](http://trac.cae.tntech.edu/ttuthesis/log/trunk/ttuthesis.cls)

Comment: How would I use git for this? As far as I know git is for versioning software repositories, and doesn't have a way to do this kind of edit highlighting. Also I'm on windows.

Answer (score 3):

Found a script called LatexDiff that will compare two latex documents and create a 3rd showing the differences between them. Not quite automated but better than doing it manually. It is a bit tricky to get working, though.

Comment: Is "your" LatexDiff the same as the [scm-latexdiff](https://bitbucket.org/paulhiemstra/scm-latexdiff) in [my answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/231635/828)?

Answer (score 3):

Have you checked out [meld](http://meldmerge.org/)?
It can easily compare up to three verions of a file and show the differences between them. The files are editable in meld itself, so you can compare, reverse changes or copy them over. There also seems to be a version control view, but I haven´t tried it yet.

[image: This is Meld´s interface]

[image: compare up to three files]

Comment: Seems a nice tool. Could you please add a little description to your answer and a link to the `meld` site?

Comment: I´ve added an other screenshot. Just click on the word "meld" and it will lead you to the download page. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. I'm sure your answer will be useful for many users.

Answer (score 2):

A bit of self promotion: my [`commenting` package](https://github.com/bordaigorl/latex-commenting) may be relevant to your needs.
It does not offer automation in the sense that you still need to mark your changes using macros.
However it allows you to mark changes / put comments per-author and has a simple interface to specify dates and exclude comments/marks before/after a certain date.

An example of usage:

```
\documentclass[draft]{article}

\usepackage{commenting}

\declareauthor{joe}{Joseph}{blue}
\declareauthor{pete}{Peter}{red}
\declareauthor{bob}{Robert}{green}

\setdefaultauthor{joe} % if no author is specified, joe is used

\authorcommand{joe}{comment} % define \joe as alias of \comment[joe]

\onlyauthors{default,joe,pete} % exclude comments from bob

% Display only comments dated between 08/01 and 15/01
\NoCommentsBefore{08/01}
\NoCommentsAfter{15/01}
% \IncludeNonDatedComments % default behaviour

\newcommand{\lipsum}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis.}

\begin{document}
\lipsum{}
\comment{I am joe}% comment by default author, not dated
\lipsum{}
\changed[pete](10/01){\lipsum}% this change is dated
\comment[bob]{This is awful}
\comment[joe]{Bla bla}
\lipsum{}
\changed[joe][Bob please check]{\lipsum}
\lipsum{}
\comment[joe]{Add comment on lipsum}
\lipsum{}
\annot[pete]{Add reference?}
\lipsum{}
\joe(16/01){I think this paragraph is unnecessary}% will be filtered out because outside date bounds
\lipsum{}
\annot[pete](12/01){Citation needed}
\lipsum{}
\end{document}
```

From which you can obtain

[image: preview]

And by just removing the `draft` option you obtain

[image: no draft preview]

Answer (score 1):

git is clearly the best option. If you're reluctant to get there, why don't you at least define commands? Something along the lines of:

```
\newcommand{\changes1215}[1]{\color{red}#1}
```

Then, for today's changes:

```
\newcommand{\changes1215}[1]{#1}
\newcommand{\changes1230}[1]{\color{red}#1}
```

That way you don't have to track down the previous changes at least, ans you can even do some kind of (very degraded) versioning.

Comment: As far as I know, `\newcommand{\changes1215}{...}\newcommand{\changes1230}{...}` shouldn't work... Does `\newcommand` do something fancy here?

Comment: no, it doesn't, and that doesn't work; just something stupid I wrote (another one, I mean). Though the idea is there, whether using letters instead of numbers, or with a `\def\afterDate{141215}\newcommand{\changes}[2]{\ifnum#1>\afterDate\textcolor{red}{#2}\fi#2}` which should do the trick, no?

Answer (score 0):

As others said before: I think you *need* to use a version control tool, and highly recommend [git](http://git-scm.com), which also works on [Windows](http://git-scm.com/download/win).

To generate a document with marked changes (to *any* prior version), I use the awesome [scm-latexdiff](https://bitbucket.org/paulhiemstra/scm-latexdiff) tool.
This might be a bit tricky to install on Windows, but should work nonetheless, since it's Python-based.

To do so, I record my changes with the version control tool (either git or [Mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com/)) and use `scm-latexdiff` to generate a PDF showing the changes with one simple command.

The image below shows the result of running

```
scm-latexdiff 123456:document.tex
```

on one of my recent documents (obvisously the command was run with a real git hash and another document name :) ).

[image: Screenshot of diff.pdf-Document]

And the best thing: this works for *any* editor and helps with selecting differences to any arbitray timepoint in the past, as long as you commited a version of your document at that point.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how. With the following R script, you don't need to manually work with LatexDiff anymore. Everything fully automated:

Step 1: Install strawberry Perl

Step 2: Download latexdiff from CTAN (the zip file)

Step 3: Unzip the latexdiff files and copy them to the strawberry\Perl\bin folder (wherever you installed strawberry)

Step 4: use the following r script (only works in windows for now, but can easily be changed for mac) and open it in R. set the directory of your files, as well as the file names, and run entire script. This should generate a pdf called “difference_highlighted.pdf”

```
#set folder and files
folder = "yourfoldername"
newfile = "new.tex"
oldfile = "old.tex"

#execute
setwd(folder)
system(paste("cmd.exe /c \"latexdiff ", oldfile," ", newfile,  " > 
difference_highlighted.tex\"" , sep = ""), intern =TRUE)
system(paste("cmd.exe /c \"pdflatex difference_highlighted.tex\""))
system(paste("cmd.exe /c \"bibtex difference_highlighted\""))
system(paste("cmd.exe /c \"pdflatex difference_highlighted.tex\""))
system(paste("cmd.exe /c \"pdflatex difference_highlighted.tex\""))
```